# Find titles of Anchor tags using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I need to find number of `anchor tags` and their `titles`  in  code mentioned below. I am using web driver, java, Selenium.

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <a></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a></a>
                </li>
             </ul>
             <ul>
               <li>
                  <a></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a></a>
                </li>
             </ul>
             <ul>
               <li>
                  <a></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a></a>
                </li>
             </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

What will be the best way to find it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by 'title' you meant the text between the anchor tags.
Use the following code:-

```
//find the div tag
WebElement divTag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div/div"));

//find all the a tags in the div tag
List<WebElement> allAnchors = divTag.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

//print number of anchor tag
System.out.println("Number of Anchor tags = " + allAnchors.size());

//print text within each anchor tag
int count=0
For(WebElement anchor : allAnchors) {
    System.out.println("Text within anchor"+ (++count) + "="+ anchor.getText());
}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: no it was not work......size shows 363  but text with in the anchor show a very few.....

Comment: can u tell me how to catch anchor tags in specific div

Comment: The problem in the HTML code you posted is that there is no unique identifier for any div tag. I have modified the answer with the very limited HTML code you have posted. But I think you'll get the idea